# MVC: How to parse string to html dom element when pass from Model/controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dom, razor

one of Model has "*description*" property which is returning html in string format. like "... ". how can I show it in view when loading the page without Js code . directly in this line:

```
   <td style="max-width: 600px">
      <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description) %>
   </td>
```

what should I put instead of "**modelItem.description**"?

I've tried

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(modelitem =>HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.description)) %>
```

but it returns the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.'
```

Comment: You can use [Html.Raw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) helper method.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini I get the same error

Comment: What's the type of `Description`? The error that you are getting suggests that `DisplayFor` Template does not accept the type of Description.

Comment: I could fix it with html.raw but without displayFor

Answer (score 0):

the reason was because of  `<%: Html.DisplayFor... %>` I cant use encoding with **Displayfor**

following is one of the correct ways to show it :

```
<%: Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.description))%>
```